# Rewriting request urls and passing to fast-cgi

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I have a server block as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        # I've tried adding "$uri.php" like so, but it downloads the php file instead.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If a request like this comes in `http://example.com/random/page`, I need Nginx to rewrite it to `http://example.com/random/page.php` without changing the url for the user. It also needs to pass that request to the other location block. If that php file doesn't exist, it should return a 404. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many possibilities:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }
    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

You should test the file existence in the `location ~ \.php$` block anyway, as mentioned in [this application note](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).